# Is performing meta-logic on data values an anti-pattern?

Tags: database-design, schema, uml, anti-patterns

Consider an object

```
Person
   firstName
   lastName
```

There is a proposal that would suggest that we use lastName = "__NOLASTNAME" for a celebrity with no last name.  This seems like an anti-pattern.  Is there a name for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called Magic String:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, it's an anti pattern. Name? Hmm, how about "*Disaster Waiting to Happen*"?

Do all applications that work with this table know that `"__NOLASTNAME"` is a special value?
Do you have more of those special values and will there be more of them?
Like `"__NOLASTNAMEBUTNOCELEBRITYEITHER"` to indicate a a stalker?
Or maybe `"__NONEOFTHEABOVE"` to indicate a company?

What happens if somebody gives their name as `"__NOLASTNAME"`? Will they automatically get treated like a celebrity? Access to Celebrity Saunas for example? Where do I sign up by the way?

Depending on what it is that you model, and how you the information will be used, you can solve it in many different ways, such as having a Celebrity entity, or adding an attribute to Person (type=person|stalker|celebrity) or flag even isCelebrity(true|false).

Comment: "Disaster waiting to happen" - best pattern name ever :-)  Great answer too.  "Special values" are a time bomb.  Do you need to know if they're a celebrity?  If not why not just leave it blank?

Comment: The real case is a little less black and white.  I was hoping for the an anti-pattern name that I could refer to rather than saying "Ronnis, sfinnie & Dave said so".  The real case involves a foreign key that is defined by multiple third parties.  You're definitely preaching to the choir on the value of going the enum route.  I was hoping for an authoritative source rather than my say so.

Comment: How about Codd for source, and 1NF for anti-pattern?

Comment: @David W, Will you consider accepting the answer if you found the answer good enough to answer your question?